# perl not able to connect database

Tags: database, perl

I am new in perl programming. I have tried the basic perl database connection and get the below error. Please any one help how to fix the issue.

```
"use" not allowed in expression at ./database.pl line 4, at end of line
syntax error at ./database.pl line 4, near "use DBI
use strict"
Execution of ./database.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

database.pl file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI
use strict;

my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "pj_order";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database;host=localhost";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "root";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Finally i have run the database.pl file and get the below error.

```
"use" not allowed in expression at ./database.pl line 4, at end of line
syntax error at ./database.pl line 4, near "use DBI
use strict"
Execution of ./database.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Semicolon.....?

Comment: Yes right ? but i another error "Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBI module) "

Comment: So? Install it.

Answer (score 3):

```
use DBI
```

should be

```
use DBI;
```

---

It's probably best if you place it after

```
use strict;
```

You should also have

```
use warnings qw( all );
```